# Installing pyobjc on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyobjc

I am facing problems installing pyobjc on my mac.
Basically I have to install pyobjc on a new Mac System in the system default python. I have so far tried easy_install, pip and downloading the pkg file and installing. All give me a error in different ways. Some give me a error saying certain safari files are missing other cant due to some permission being denied even though I am running them through sudo su.
I then found a fix.

```
    pip install pyobjc --user
```

This worked and I could access all the modules I required, but then if I try running python through sudo, I cant access those modules.
Can anyone suggest a fix for this.

NOTE: I don't mind a different method to install also. Also I have not tried brew due to some previous difficulties with it.

NOTE 2: I need to be able to access those modules using all users on the computer, the root user and me(the non-root user)

Comment: one idea is to check your path and python,sudo user might have installed and pointed to different path

Comment: There is just one python installed on my computer. Just the system python that comes with the machine. It is a new machine freshly installed mac. I dont know how it might install into a different path? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

i had to (temporarily) move (using sudo) /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth to another name before I could install the current pyobjc.

This is what works for me:

```
sudo mv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth_orig
pip install --upgrade pyobjc
sudo mv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth_orig /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Extras.pth
```

It appears that something in the .pth file interferes with the install, but does not impede running pyobjc.

Answer (score 1):

> but then if I try running python through sudo, I cant access those
>   modules.

Because `sudo python` basically means run python as some other user (root by default). That user may have a different set of **environment variables**, including `$PATH`.

Some of linux distributions use older Python version for root user,like `centos`.If the Python verison you're running with `sudo` isn't correct,you can't access those modules installed by `pip`.

So in my opinion,if you didn't get permission issues,you don't need to use `sudo` ,using sudo might bring unexpected mistakes(most `environment variables` issues),maybe `chown` or `chmod` can fix those issues.

So here are my plans:

**Plan A**:  The best way is to try to use `virtualenv`.

**Plan B**:  Install modules without `sudo` command,if got permission errors(not very common),try [--user](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs) .

> Install to the Python user install directory for your platform.
>   Typically ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%Python on Windows.

In most cases,you should modify your `PYTHONPATH`.See details from [How do I access packages installed by pip --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112756/how-do-i-access-packages-installed-by-pip-user).

**Plan C**: All related commands are executed with sudo.`sudo pip install (all modules)` and `sudo python script.py`.Not a good idea.

Comment: I got errors when installing using sudo, so I used --user. But I need to be able to access the modules through all the users.

Comment: How would I go through using virtualenv. I have not used that before.

Comment: @ShdwKnght333  Access the modules,have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112756/how-do-i-access-packages-installed-by-pip-user).And you can also read [virtualenv doc](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).