# setuptools is installed but I can't import it

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tried to install with `pip`:

```
user@Ubuntu ~/ $ sudo pip --no-cache-dir install --user -U setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /home/coder/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (40.6.3)
```

But when I wanted to `import` it, then it's not importing anymore.

```
user@Ubuntu ~/ $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access packages installed by \`pip --user\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112756/how-do-i-access-packages-installed-by-pip-user)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this from this link here 
[Correct command for pip upgrade](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) my solution is below:

```
User@Ubuntu ~/Documents/RE $ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/coder/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (18.1)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/06/754589caf971b0d2d48f151c2586f62902d93dc908e2fd9b9b9f6aa3c9dd/setuptools-40.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (573kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 573kB 666kB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/47/1dfa4795e24fd6f93d5d58602dd716c3f101cfd5a77cd9acbe519b44a0a9/wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed setuptools-40.6.3 wheel-0.32.3

user@Ubuntu ~/Documents/RE $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>>
```

So correct command was this:

```
user@ubuntu ~/Documents/RE $ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```